# How to understand "nuget restore" answer

Tags: xml, nuget

I'm having problems again with my NuGet packages. I have downloaded the lastest `NuGet.exe`, and in the Visual Studio solutions directory of my application's solution, I have launched following command (using Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017):

```
nuget restore -verbosity detailed
```

I get the question to enter my e-mailaddress and password for NuGet purposes, the Microsoft Authenticator app on my smartphone tells me the question will be approved, ...

At the end, I get following error message:

```
Errors in packages.config projects
  Unable to find version '1.52.1960' of package 'Own_Product.MFS.Server'.
    C:\Users\DDM\.nuget\packages\: Package 'Own_Product.MFS.Server.1.52.1960' is not found
    on source 'C:\Users\DDM\.nuget\packages\'.
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'Own_Product.MFS.Server.1.52.1960' is not found 
    on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Package 'Own_Product.MFS.Server.1.52.1960' is not found 
    on source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'.
    https://Own_Product.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/Own_ProductNuGetFeed/nuget/v2:
    Package 'Own_Product.MFS.Server.1.52.1960' is not found 
    on source 'https://Own_Product.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/Own_ProductNuGetFeed/nuget/v2'.
```

My question is: how can I read this error message?

```
  C:\Users\DDM\.nuget\packages\: Package 'Own_Product.MFS.Server.1.52.1960' is not found
  on source 'C:\Users\DDM\.nuget\packages\'.
```

=> This is obvious: the "NuGet Restore" failed, so the fact that this package is not there is normal.

```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'Own_Product.MFS.Server.1.52.1960' is not found
  on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
```

=> The package is an "Own_Product" package, obviously it's not found between the Microsoft packages.

```
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Package 'Own_Product.MFS.Server.1.52.1960' is not found 
  on source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'.
```

=> at first glance, this is normal: "https//api.nuget.org" looks like a general website, it is normal for such a website not to contain information about a specific "Own_Product" package. Is this correct or is the content of this website determined by the username I've provided?

```
  https://Own_Product.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/Own_ProductNuGetFeed/nuget/v2:
  Package 'Own_Product.MFS.Server.1.52.1960' is not found
  on source 'https://Own_Product.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/Own_ProductNuGetFeed/nuget/v2'.
```

=> when surfing to that URL, this is what I see:

```
<service xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app"
         xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
         xml:base="https://Own_Productstore.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/Own_ProductstoreNuGetFeed/nuget/v2">
    <workspace>
        <atom:title type="text">Default</atom:title>
        <collection href="Packages">
            <atom:title type="text">Packages</atom:title>
        </collection>
    </workspace>
</service>
```

In other words, this does not contain any reference towards any package. Is this normal or is there an issue here?